# Class initialization failing

Tags: python, class, in-class-initialization

```
# Class and Instance Variables
class Dog:
    kind = 'canine'

    def __int__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.tricks = []

d = Dog('Fido')
e = Dog('Buddy')

print(d.kind)
print(e.kind)
print(d.name)
print(e.name)
```

---

Error report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dog.py", line 13, in <module>
    d = Dog('Fido')
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: Typo: `__int__` should be `__init__`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have correct the mistake you have pointed out.

Comment: You are welcome :) I've re-posted my comment as an answer. If your problem is solved, feel free to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Otherwise, add details to your question or ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo. The method `__int__` should be called `__init__`.