# getting TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters

Tags: python-3.x

class Parent():

```
def __int__(self,last_name,eye_color):
    print("Parent constructor called!")
    self.last_name=last_name
    self.eye_color=eye_color
```

class Child(Parent):
    def **init**(self,last_name,eye_color,number_of_toys):
        print("Child constructor Called")
        Parent.**init**(self,last_name,eye_color)
        self.number_of_toys=number_of_toys

miley_cyrus = Child("Cyrus","Blue",5)

print(miley_cyrus.last_name)
print(miley_cyrus.number_of_toys)

getting

Comment: Please fix the formatting. Also, what is the last line ("getting")?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class initialization failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611351/class-initialization-failing)

Answer (score 1):

`__int__` is not `__init__`. The method you've defined is for converting an object to an integer, which understandably does not accept any parameters.